# Price + 20% of price in PHP

Tags: php, percentage, multiplication

PHP newbie here. I've created a function that increases prices based on their price range:

```
function update_price ( $price) {
  If (isset($price) ) {
    if ($price < 60 ) {
      return $price + 40;
    } 
  elseif ($price >= 60 && $price < 100) {
    return $price + 60;
  } 
  elseif ($price >= 100 && $price < 200) {
    return $price + 70;
  }
  elseif ($price >= 200 && $price < 300) {
    return $price + 80;
  }
  elseif ($price >= 300 && $price < 450) {
    return $price + 90;
  }
  elseif ($price >= 450) {
    return $price + ($price * .2);
  }
} 
}
```

The function is called when I import a CSV file. Works great, except for the last part of the function. I'm trying to raise the price of those qualifying products by 20%, so I'm taking $price and adding ($price * .2). But a product that was $628.74 is coming out as $754,888.00 instead of $754.88.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Lots of typographical errors in the code you are showing (missing several right parentheses). Hard to tell what's really going on since who knows what else may be incorrectly typed. Why don't you just copy/paste the actual code you want to ask about into the question rather than retyping it?

Comment: You've also got a typo in your expected result. $628.74 * 1.2 should come out as $754.488.

Comment: lurker - You're right. I've corrected the parentheses. Like I said, total newbie here and I copied/pasted the wrong version.

Comment: Your function works fine. The problem must be in how you are outputting the result. https://3v4l.org/nAgcT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK that PHP returns 754.488, it's the same value returned by a calculator:
628.74÷5+628.74=754.488

Here you would need to round the precision to 2 decimal numbers, this can be done with the round() function.

Also, I would write your function like this:

```
    function update_price($price) {
        if((!$price) || (!is_numeric($price)) || ($price <= 0)) // initial price is not valid
                return -1;

        if($price >= 450) return $price+round($price/5, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
        if($price >= 300) return $price+90;
        if($price >= 200) return $price+80;
        if($price >= 100) return $price+70;
        if($price >= 60)  return $price+60;
        return $price+40;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what "$price/5, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN" does?

Comment: $price/5 is like doing $price/100*20 , the round() function is the one that will round your number to 2 decimal numbers. Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what your doing to give you that error but

Testcode

```
$base = 628.74;
$change = round($base * 0.2,2);
$new = $base + $change;
$allatonce = round(($base+($base*0.2)),2);
print_r(array($base,$change,$new,$allatonce));
```

Output

> Array ( [0] => 628.74 [1] => 125.75 [2] => 754.49 [3] => 754.49 )

the all at once value would fit your needs.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different to the OP's original solution?

Comment: its not missing the ) after ($price >= 450 
it also rounds to 2 dp.